# MySQL - Get most recent result in each group

Tags: mysql

SQL Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd34e6/1

There are multiple task entries with different timestamps. I am trying to get the latest entry for each taskId as shown by the desired results.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE TaskStatuses
(
    taskId INT,
    status VARCHAR(255),
    timestamp DATETIME
);
```

**Current result:**

```
1   Complete    1530295000
3   Complete    1530294900
3   Active  1530294100
1   Active  1530294000
4   Complete    1530293900
2   Active  1530293500
1   Paused  1530293000
1   Active  1530292000
4   Active  1530292000
```

**Desired result:**

```
1  Complete  1530295000
3  Complete  1530294900
4  Complete  1530293900
2  Active  1530293500
```

**Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)**

```
SELECT a.taskId, a.status, unix_timestamp(a.timestamp) as unix
FROM TaskStatuses a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT taskId, MAX(timestamp) timestamp
    FROM TaskStatuses
    GROUP BY taskId
) b ON a.taskId = b.taskId AND a.timestamp = b.timestamp
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I actually didn't come across that answer which was great!

Comment: Keep in mind that the query you now use can return multiple records for the same group when the max value is the same it does not handle ties.